# Sum of bitwise XOR of each subarray weighted by length

Tags: algorithm, c, programming-challenge, dynamic-programming

here is the problem statement

> You are given an array *a* of length *n* consisting of non-negative integers.
>
> You have to calculate the value of \$\sum_{l=1}^n \sum_{r=l}^n f(l,r)\cdot (r - l + 1)\$ where \$f(l, r)\$ is \$a_l \oplus a_{l+1} \oplus ... \oplus a_{r-1} \oplus a_r\$ (the character \$\oplus\$ denotes bitwise XOR)
>
> Since the answer can be very large, print it modulo \$998244353\$.
>
> **Input**
>
> The first line contains an integer *n* (\$1 \le n \le 3\cdot 10^5\$ - the length of the array *a*).
>
> The second line contains *n* integers \$a_1, a_2, ... a_n (0 \le a_i \le 10^9)\$
>
> **Output**
>
> Print one integer - the value of \$\sum_{l=1}^n \sum_{r=l}^n f(l,r)\cdot (r - l + 1)\$ taken modulo \$998244353\$.
>
> **Examples**
> input
> `3`
> `1 3 2`
> output
> `12`
>
> input
> `4`
> `39 68 31 80`
> output
> `1337`
>
> input
> `7`
> `313539461 779847196 221612534 488613315 633203958 394620685 761188160`
> output
> `257421502`

Here is my code, it works but is slow for the given values in the problem. (I know only C, a beginner at that).
Could you provide faster code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

long long int f(long long int *a,long long int b, long long int c);
long long int sum(long long int arraysize, long long int*a);

long long int main ()
{
    clock_t start, end;
    double cpu_time_used;
    long long int n, ans;
    scanf("%lld", &n);

    long long int *a = (long long int *)malloc(n*sizeof(long long int));
    for (long long int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        scanf("%lld", a+i);
    }
    start = clock();
    ans = sum(n , a)%998244353;
    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%lld", ans);
    free(a);
    printf("\nf() took %f seconds to execute \n", cpu_time_used);
}

long long int f(long long int *a,long long int n1, long long int n2)
{
    long long int c = a[n1];
    for (long long int i = n1+1; i <=n2; i++)
    {
        c = c ^ a[i];
    }
    return c;
}

long long int sum(long long int arraysize , long long int *a)
{
    long long int value= 0;
    for (long long int i = 0 ; i < arraysize; i++)
    {
        for (long long int j = i, count = 1 ; j < arraysize ; j++, count++)
        {
            value += f(a, i, j)*count;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

I was told to precalculate some values, and its time complexity can be reduced to O(n) by ChatGPT.

Comment: This problem is "D. Sum of XOR Functions" by the way. Some people have posted solutions for it online.

Answer (score 7):

**Choosing `int` as the return type for `main()` for portability and compatibility":**

Portably, `main()` only returns `int`. Best to return an `int` and not a `long long`.

```
// long long int main ()
int main(void)
```

**Do not cast the result of `malloc` and family:**

```
// long long int *a = (long long int *)malloc(n*sizeof(long long int));
   long long int *a = malloc (n * sizeof a[0]);
```

`malloc()` returns a generic `void *` that is implicitly converted to any other pointer type. As such, its result need not be casted and only serves to clutter one's code.

**Check the return value of library functions:**

> **If a function be advertised to return an error code in the event of difficulties, thou shalt check for that code, yea, even though the
> checks triple the size of thy code and produce aches in thy typing
> fingers, for if thou thinkest "it cannot happen to me", the gods shall
> surely punish thee for thy arrogance.** — [The Ten Commandments For C
> Programmers](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ten-commandments.html)

`malloc()` and family returns `NULL` to indicate failure. Failure to check it risks invoking undefined behavior by a subsequent `NULL` pointer dereference.

```
// What does a stand for?
long long int *a = malloc (n * sizeof a);

if(!a) { 
   complain();
}
```

`scanf()` returns the number of conversions successfully performed. We ought to check its return value to ensure that we did indeed read a `long long int`.

```
if(scanf("%lld", &n) != 1) {
   complain();
}
```

**Use `const`:**

The parameters that are not changed anywhere in the function should be `const`-qualified.

```
// Again, what do a, n1, and n2 stand for?
static long long int f(const long long int *a , long long int n1, long long int n2)
```

**`sum()` and `f()` should have `static` linkage:**

As the functions are only used in this translation unit, they should be declared with having internal linkage:

```
// long long int f(long long int *a,long long int b, long long int c);
// long long int sum(long long int arraysize, long long int*a);

// What do f, a, b, and c stand for?
static long long int f(long long int *a, long long int b, long long int c);
static long long int sum(long long int arraysize, long long int *a);
```

**Naming and formatting:**

Function and variable names should be descriptive and meaningful, providing clarity to readers. Using cryptic or overly short names, such as `f` for a function or `a`, `b`, and `c` for variables, can hinder comprehension and should be avoided.

Choose a consistent strategy for whitespace and other text formatting. I suggest using an code formatter like GNU indent.

**Minor:**

We can eliminate redundant forward declarations by defining the functions before `main()`.

Answer (score 7):

- `long long int main()` invokes UB. `main` must be declared as `int`.
- `long long` is an overkill. It is guaranteed that \$0 \le a_i \le 10^9\$. Recall that \$2^{10} = 1024\$ is slightly larger than \$10^3\$, so \$10^9\$ is surely less than \$2^{30}\$. All \$a_i\$, and all XORs, comfortably fit into a 32-bit-wide type.

  So do the indices.
- Intermediate `value`s computed in `sum` may overflow. You need to use addition (and multiplication) modulo `998244353`.
- Computing \$f\$ takes \$O(n)\$ times. Computing it in the double loop drives the time complexity to \$O(n^3)\$.

  It is worth noticing that we have \$x \oplus x = 0\$ and \$x \oplus 0 = x\$. It means that \$f(l, r) = f(0, r) \oplus f(0, l-1)\$. In other words, you only need to compute cumulative XORs - in \$O(n)\$ time - to reduce the overall time complexity to \$O(n^2)\$.

  I don't know how to reduce it further. XOR does not interact nicely with neither addition nor multiplication. I will be very surprised to see an \$O(n)\$ solution.

Comment: "long long int main() invokes UB. main must be declared as int." may be OK given the C spec's "or in some other implementation-defined manner."  C23dr § 5.1.2.2.1 1

Comment: If "long long is an overkill.", perhaps post an alternative. `long`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I think _32-bit-wide type_ is enough of an alternative. `int32_t` shall be good.

Answer (score 5):

**Efficiency only answer**

Rather than recalculate `f(l, r)` repeatedly, recognize that  `f(l, r)` is the same as `f(0, l-1) ^ f(0, r)` and so form a table `xor[r+1]`.

It is much faster.

---

Illustrative code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t bitwise_f(const uint32_t *a, size_t left, size_t right) {
  uint32_t c = 0;
  for (size_t i = left; i <= right; i++) {
    c = c ^ a[i];
  }
  return c;
}

uint32_t bitwise_sum(size_t n, const uint32_t a[n]) {
// or
//  uint32_t bitwise_sum(size_t n, uint32_t *a) {
  uint64_t sum = 0;
  for (size_t left = 0; left < n; left++) {
    uint64_t count = 1;
    for (size_t r = left; r < n; r++) {
      sum += bitwise_f(a, left, r) * count;
      sum %= 998244353u;
      count++;
    }
    sum %= 998244353u;
  }
  return (uint32_t) sum;
}

uint32_t bitwise_sum_alt(size_t n, const uint32_t a[n]) {
  uint32_t xor[n+1];
  uint32_t c = 0;
  xor[0] = c;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    c = c ^ a[i];
    xor[i+1] = c;
  }

  uint64_t sum = 0;
  for (size_t left = 0; left < n; left++) {
    uint64_t count = 1;
    for (size_t right = left; right < n; right++) {
      sum += (xor[right + 1 ] ^ xor[left]) * count;
      count++;
      sum %= 998244353u;
    }
    // sum %= 998244353u;
  }
  return (uint32_t) sum;
}

// Test code
#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define BITWISE_NO_EXPECT -1

double bitwise_test(int64_t expected_sum, size_t n, const uint32_t a[n]) {
  clock_t start = clock();
  uint32_t sum = bitwise_sum_alt(n, a);
  clock_t end = clock();
  double cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("Sum:%" PRIu32 " ", sum);
  printf("f() took %f seconds to execute. \n", cpu_time_used);
  if (expected_sum != BITWISE_NO_EXPECT && sum != expected_sum) {
    printf("sum:%" PRIu32 " does not equal expected:%" PRIi64 "\n", //
        sum, expected_sum);
  }
  return cpu_time_used;
}

void bitwise_test_large(size_t nmax) {
  for (size_t n = 64; n <= nmax; n *= 2) {
    uint32_t *a = malloc(sizeof a[0] * n);
    assert(a);
    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) {
      a[i] = (uint32_t) rand();
    }
    printf("Size:%zu  ", n);
    bitwise_test(BITWISE_NO_EXPECT, n, a);
    fflush(stdout);
  }
}

int main(void) {
#if 1
  bitwise_test(12, 3, (uint32_t[]) {1, 3, 2});
  bitwise_test(1337, 4, (uint32_t[]) {39, 68, 31, 80});
  bitwise_test(257421502, 7, (uint32_t[]) {313539461, 779847196, 221612534,
          488613315, 633203958, 394620685, 761188160});
    bitwise_test_large(1u << 18);
  return 0;
#endif
  size_t n;
  scanf("%zu", &n);
  uint32_t *a = malloc(sizeof a[0] * n);
  assert(a);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%" SCNu32, a + i);
  }
  bitwise_test(BITWISE_NO_EXPECT, n, a);
  free(a);
}
```

Output with `bitwise_sum()` (OP's approach)

```
Sum:12 f() took 0.000000 seconds to execute. 
Sum:1337 f() took 0.000000 seconds to execute. 
Sum:257421502 f() took 0.000000 seconds to execute. 
Size:64  Sum:201216235 f() took 0.000000 seconds to execute. 
Size:128  Sum:935200203 f() took 0.000000 seconds to execute. 
Size:256  Sum:236376682 f() took 0.000000 seconds to execute. 
Size:512  Sum:702872695 f() took 0.016000 seconds to execute. 
Size:1024  Sum:564088685 f() took 0.031000 seconds to execute. 
Size:2048  Sum:144981798 f() took 0.313000 seconds to execute. 
Size:4096  Sum:855006432 f() took 2.328000 seconds to execute. 
Size:8192  Sum:627587314 f() took 18.359000 seconds to execute. 
Size:16384  Sum:777920909 f() took 145.171000 seconds to execute. 
...
```

Output with `bitwise_sum_alt()` that uses a table look-up

```
Sum:12 f() took 0.000000 seconds to execute. 
Sum:1337 f() took 0.000000 seconds to execute. 
Sum:257421502 f() took 0.000000 seconds to execute. 
Size:64  Sum:201216235 f() took 0.000000 seconds to execute. 
Size:128  Sum:935200203 f() took 0.000000 seconds to execute. 
Size:256  Sum:236376682 f() took 0.000000 seconds to execute. 
Size:512  Sum:702872695 f() took 0.000000 seconds to execute. 
Size:1024  Sum:564088685 f() took 0.000000 seconds to execute. 
Size:2048  Sum:144981798 f() took 0.016000 seconds to execute. 
Size:4096  Sum:855006432 f() took 0.000000 seconds to execute. 
Size:8192  Sum:627587314 f() took 0.047000 seconds to execute. 
Size:16384  Sum:777920909 f() took 0.109000 seconds to execute. 
Size:32768  Sum:227211329 f() took 0.609000 seconds to execute. 
Size:65536  Sum:538845010 f() took 2.407000 seconds to execute. 
Size:131072  Sum:913595480 f() took 9.640000 seconds to execute. 
Size:262144  Sum:776716501 f() took 38.749000 seconds to execute.
```

---

Possible other simplifications exists.

Answer (score 3):

**Offset from 0 or 1?**

Keep in mind the posted algorithm uses array indexing from 1 and C uses offsets from 0.

As I see it, OP has done that correctly.

**Array size type**

Use `size_t` for array sizing and indexing.  `long long` is likely unnecessarily wide.  Using `size_t` also conveys the idea that the object is for indexing/sizing.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
// long long int f(long long int *a,long long int b, long long int c);
long long int f(long long int *a, size_t b, size_t c);
```

**Handle unexpected values**

A more generic form of `f()` would behave well even if `l > r` (`n1 > n2`).

```
// long long int c = a[n1];
long long int c = 0;
// for (long long int i = n1+1; i <=n2; i++)
for (long long int i = n1; i <=n2; i++)
  ...
```

This matches posted formula better.

**Use `const` for refenced data**

Its faster (with weak compilers), Allows calling on `const` arrays and 3) conveys the constant idea of data being processed.

```
// long long int f(long long int *a, ...) {
long long int f(const long long int *a, ...) {
```

**Save `long long` for intermediate calculations**

Improve speed by using narrower types when possible.  (If on a smaller than 64-bit machine.)

```
// long long int f(long long int *a,long long int n1, long long int n2) {
//    long long int c = a[n1];
//    for (long long int i = n1+1; i <=n2; i++)

uint32_t int f(const uint32_t *a, size_t n1, size_t n2) {
    uint32_t c = 0;
    for (size_t i = n1; i <=n2; i++)
```

**Less common function names**

Consider you code may get used in a larger program.  Names like `f`, `sum` will certainly collide.

```
// f
bitwise_f  // example
```

**Consider *unsigned* types for problems involving logical operations**

**Consider types that fit the range of the problem**

With `0≤a[i]≤1,000,000,000)`, `a[i]` fits in a 32-bit integer like  `uint32_t`.

**Improve presentation**

Use an auto-formatter for code.

**Cleaner `for()`**

Avoid packing code in `for()` statements.

---

Putting the above together (and some other ideas)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t bitwise_f(uint32_t *a, size_t left, size_t right) {
  uint32_t c = 0;
  for (size_t i = left; i <= right; i++) {
    c = c ^ a[i];
  }
  return c;
}

uint32_t bitwise_sum(size_t n, uint32_t a[n]) {
// or
//  uint32_t bitwise_sum(size_t n, uint32_t *a) {
  uint64_t sum = 0;
  for (size_t left = 0; left < n; left++) {
    uint64_t count = 1;
    for (size_t right = left; right < n; right++) {
      // Note 64-bit multiplication and addition.
      sum += bitwise_f(a, left, right) * count;
      sum %= 998244353u;
      count++;
    }
  }
  return (uint32_t) sum;
}
```

Comment: The usual reminder that `uint32_t` is an _optional_ type; I recommend `uint_fast32_t` for pedantic portability.  Best to localise the choice to a single `typedef` in case of changing mind again later...

Comment: @TobySpeight Agree about `typedef`.  With singleton objects, `uint_fast32_t` is better than `uint_least32_t`.  With _arrays_, `uint_least32_t` can readily outperform `uint_fast32_t`  due to better caching of the smaller object - for the rare cases they are, in fact, different.

Comment: Yes, "fast" seems more appropriate than "least" here.

Answer (score 1):

#### Efficiency

As noted in other answers, your code takes \$O(n^3)\$ time to run. It can be reduced to \$O(n^2)\$ by computing the cumulative XOR, but that's still quite slow for \$n \approx 3\cdot10^5\$. The problem can be solved in \$O(n \log U)\$ time, where \$U\$ is the maximum element in the array, and it's probably what the author of it intended:

If we split each number \$a_i\$ to its bits, \$a_i = b_i^0 + 2b_i^1 + 2^2 b_i^2 + 2^3 b_i^3 + ...\$, we can define \$f_j(l,r) = b_l^j \oplus b_{l+1}^j \oplus \cdots \oplus b_{r}^j \$, and notice that \$f(l, r) = f_0(l, r) + 2 f_1(l, r) + 2^2 f_2(l, r) + \cdots\$. Therefore $$\sum_{l=1}^{n} \sum_{r=l}^{n} f(l, r) (r-l+1) = \sum_{j=0}^{\log_2(U)}{2^j \sum_{l=1}^{n} \sum_{r=l}^{n} f_j(l, r) (r-l+1)}$$
And we reduced the problem to \$\log U\$ problems where \$a_i \in \{0 , 1\}\$.

To solve the problem when \$a_i \in \{0, 1\}\$, we can define \$b_i\$ (for \$0 \leq i \leq n\$) to be the xor of the first \$i\$ values of \$a\$, as in the other answers. If we do that, we have $$\sum_{l=1}^n \sum_{r=l}^n f(l, r) (r-l+1) = \sum_{l=0}^{n-1} \sum_{r=l+1}^{n} (b_l \oplus b_r) (r - l) = \sum_{l=0}^{n-1} (\sum_{r=l+1}^{n} (b_l \oplus b_r) r - l \sum_{r=l+1}^{n} (b_l \oplus b_r))$$

to calculate this, we can maintain \$\sum_{r=l+1}^{n} b_r, \sum_{r=l+1}^{n} (1\oplus b_r), \sum_{r=l+1}^{n} r b_r, \sum_{r=l+1}^{n} r (1\oplus b_r)\$ as we iterate over the array.